# Как унаследовать в js от класса родителя функцию со всеми ее значениями?

Tags: javascript, классы, методы, extend

Есть класс Animal и класс Rabbit, который должен унаследовать функцию :function moveElement от Animal, вот эту часть кода, не переписывая его полностью:

```
function moveElement(arr,from,to) {
  arr.splice(to,0,arr.splice(from,1)[0]);
  return arr;
};

if (arr[0]>arr[1]) document.write(moveElement(arr,0,1));
```

Rabbit должен вывести document.write(moveElement(arr,0,1)); уже с учетом передвинутых элементов массива, т.е. массив - 3,2,4,1.
Вот примерный код:

```js
var arr = [4, 3, 2, 1];

function Animal() {

  function moveElement(arr, from, to) {
    arr.splice(to, 0, arr.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
  }

  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) 
    document.write(moveElement(arr, 0, 1));
    alert('hello');
  
}

var animal = new Animal();

function Rabbit() {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments);
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
```

Возможно полное изменение кода.

Comment: что за тяга ставить `{}` где надо и не надо? Отформатируй приложенный код

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Что и зачем нужно унаследовать? И что значит это ваше унаследовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужно поддерживать legacy браузеры, для реализации наследования лучше использовать [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Если вам нужно, чтобы разные объекты работали с одним и тем же набором данных, просто передайте его им, например в конструктор. Сложные типы в javascript передаются по ссылке — все объекты будут редактировать общие данные:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  moveElement(from, to) {
    [this.values[from], this.values[to]] = [this.values[to], this.values[from]] 
    // this.values.splice(to, 0, this.values.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return this;
  }
  act() {
    if (this.values[0] > this.values[1]) {
      this.moveElement(0, 1);
    }
  }
}
class Rabbit extends Animal {
  act() {
    if (this.values[1] > this.values[2]) {
      this.moveElement(1, 2);
    }
  }
}

var values = [4, 3, 2, 1]
var animal = new Animal(values);
animal.act(); // 3, 4, 2, 1
var rabbit = new Rabbit(values);
rabbit.act(); // 3, 2, 4, 1

console.log(rabbit.values.join(', '));
```